# Windows Phone panorama capital letters?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to have capital letters (abbreviation of company name) in the panorama title, but writing in caps results in cutting off top part of letters. How to get the text normally visible in title of panorama?

Comment: edit the panorama's HeaderTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

The design language on Windows Phone has guidelines on how you would do things the way that is recommended. One of them is to keep [application titles in lower case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680270%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx).
Although not an official Microsoft blog post, Jeff Wilcox (who does work for Microsoft Windows Phone team as the primary user interface developer though) has an excellent take on the [Windows Phone design guidelines](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/metroradio-design/) as well.

Maybe you should re-think your desire to write in upper case?

Comment: There are instances where branding is important. Take for example, Microsoft's own app 'HealthVault' which uses TitleCase

Comment: @willmel of course it's important. There are also Microsoft Windows Phone software that totally falls outside the design language: http://winsource.com/2012/03/05/microsoft-fails-to-follow-its-own-metroui-guidelines/

Comment: That's an iPhone app... you could consider that just trying to get users using a 'Metro' UI.

Comment: Nevermind, if you follow the full link there's a correct picture. Regardless, it's not in the app store. and HealthVault is a much better example of when it's appropriate